# Facebook Like button & Twitter Follow button not inline on iOS browsers (Chrome / Safari)

Tags: ios, css, facebook

If you visit: http://onrepeatthisweek.tumblr.com/ and drag your viewport down to around 400px and click the down arrow next to O&O&O&O you'll see that the Twitter and Facebook buttons sit on the same line.

However if you were to do the same on Safari or Chrome iOS you'd see that the Facebook Like button sits on a new line underneath the Twitter button.

Both elements have 'display:inline-block !important;' applied to them.

I don't have Safari 6 so can't debug remotely.

I'd like to make it so that the Facebook and Twitter buttons are on the same line on iOS. Can anybody help?

Many thanks.
Thomas.

Comment: Fixed this, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Adding position:relative; & width:auto !important; to both elements seemed to fix this although I suspect it was the latter that actually had an impact and I probably only needed to apply it to the Facebook Like button.